# Group permissions allow, but still get permission denied

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I have a ext4 partition and I've set the group owner for all subdirectors to mygroup:

```
# chgrp -R mygroup /mount/abc
# chmod -R g+swrx /mount/abc
```

My user is part of that group. Inside that partition is a folder who is owned by user 'nobody' and now by the group 'mygroup'. My user is part of 'mygroup'. Here's an ls -l:

```
myuser@host:/mount/abc/folder$ ls -l
drwxr-sr-x 2 nobody      mygroup      4096 Apr 25 12:08 ./
drwxrwsrwx 6 nobody      mygroup      4096 Apr 24 07:57 ../
-rw-r-xr-- 1 otheruser   mygroup    159539 Apr 23 23:44 test.png*

myuser@host:/mount/abc/folder$ groups myuser
myuser : mygroup {... a list of other groups also...} 

myuser@host:/mount/abc/folder$ rm test.png 
rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘test.png’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘test.png’: Permission denied

myuser@host:/mount/abc/folder$ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘test.txt’: Permission denied
```

Note that I cannot delete nor create a file that is owned by a group that my user is a part of.

I guess I don't fully understand how groups work. I thought if you were part of a group then you inherit the permissions of that group. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the permissions triad is owner-group-world. Above you can see drwxr-sr-x for the directory. So the group's permission is r-s. It looks like the chmod -R didn't recursively set the permissions to rwx. When I flip the w bit for the group permission of the folder, it works.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Did you recently add that user to that group, without logging out/in between? Then "groups" will show the group but the user does not have the group permissions yet.

You can show your effective groups using

```
$ id
```

As an example, if I add my user `ps` to the group `fax` and then type

```
$ id
```

it does not show the group `fax`, but

```
$ groups ps
```

shows `fax`.

Doing `su` to your own user gives you the new group affiliation:

```
$ su ps
$ id
```

The output now also contains `fax`.

Comment: This is really helpful to know. Especially the 'sudo <username>' part.

Comment: log in/out is so obvious that I missed the point, many thanks buddy!

Comment: @peschü I can't get the sudo bit to work. If I just do `sudo ubuntu` I get `sudo: ubuntu: command not found`

Comment: @beldaz: sudo is a program that needs to be installed. `apt-get install sudo` and you should be fine.

Comment: @peschü I have `sudo` and use it regularly. The error I showed you is complaining that the command `ubuntu` (i.e., the user name) is not a recognised command. I do not think your suggestion is syntactically correct - perhaps it works in your case because `ps` happens also to be a command as well as a user name.

Comment: @beldaz oh no! You are right! syntactically correct it is `su <username>`. I have edited the post.

Comment: damn the old log out/log in again work every time.

Comment: Still no go. "id" shows me I'm " groups=1000(username),27(sudo),33(www-data)" and yet no access to files that are -rwxrw-r-- and another user, same group.

Comment: `su ps` .......... Hilarious, but brilliant. Thanks! Using `su` worked perfectly for something which stubbornly wanted to retain its old login instead of opening a new one!

Comment: Personally, no matter how many times I logged out and in of Ubuntu 22, `id` still didn't show the new group. I had to reboot the machine

Answer (score 11):

The method that you have used seems to be correct. I just now tried to replicate it, and it worked just fine.

I am not sure if there is a typo, but there is a slight problem with the command. There is no need to have "mygroup" mentioned in there. The following works

```
# chmod -R g+swrx /mount/abc
```

Even, you can remove the `s` bit, just do `g+rwx`. After you have changed the permissions, and you do `ls -l`, it should display the relevant privileges.

Comment: I removed the typo with the groupname. The directory has the wrx permissions on it when you do ls -l, and it is owned by nobody:mygroup. Even though myuser is part of mygroup, myuser still cannot create/delete files. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

Directories need x bit set (for directory that bit is seen as search bit) to open. So I use tree so I can get only the folder set and avoid the nightmare of having all the files set as executables ( the option for tree is  `-d List directories only.`):

```
sudo tree -faid /mount/abc | xargs -L1 -I{} sudo chmod 755  "{}"
```

**Warning!!!** you should have this into considerations:

- using chmod or chown recursive on root `/` directory or system directories will destroy your OS (actually anything recursive on `/` directory or system directories is dangerous)
- this is not a good security practice to set permission bulk like that

Comment: Great thanks! The words "Directories need x bit set" solved my problem!
I did "sudo chmod g+x <parent dir path>" and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot remove the file because the group `mygroup` doesn't have write permissions on the file `test.png` as well as the folder. For write operations to work on the file the file permissions should look like:

```
-rw-rwxr-- 1 otheruser   mygroup    159539 Apr 23 23:44 test.png*
```

If you take a closer look at the permission format

```
duuugggooo
```

The first three placeholders `uuu` are user **r**ead, **w**rite and e**x**ecute. The next three placeholders `ggg` are for the group and `ooo` for others. In the snippet posted by OP group is missing the **w**rite permission.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the accepted answer (since I can't comment yet):

If you use software like BitVise to create a SSH connection to your server, simply closing & re-opening a terminal will not count as logging in & out. It **will** do things like reload your `~/.bashrc`, but ***not*** perform the actual group updates (if you added the group in your "login" session).
For this to take effect you would have to fully logout and login again with your SSH-key/credentials.